# wmv to flv using mencoder

Tags: conversion, flv, wmv, mencoder

I am trying to convert .wmv video files to .flv format, .flv will be played in JW Player

I use the following command

```
-of lavf -oac pcm -lameopts abr:br=48 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=flv:vbitrate=480 -srate 22050
```

The file got transcoded but still the video runs fast in such a way that the 1minute video runs in 3 seconds

I tried with various commands and i was not able to succeed?

What parameter should be passed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on [mencoder mailing list](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mencoder-users/2009-January/009704.html):

**Mencoder can't read fps from a wmv container.**

You could force an fps value or ease your troubles and use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/):

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.wmv output_video.flv
```

If you want to use the encoding parameters you were asking for in your mencoder command (I might be wrong about mencoder default bit rate units):

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.wmv -b 480m -acodec pcm_s8  -ab 48k -ar 22050  output_video.flv
```

Comment: When i tried with the above command i got this error "Unsupported codec (id=86056) for input stream #0.0". Any up gradation of ffmpeg has to be done?

Comment: what is input stream #0.0? this msg shows same error (http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2009-January/018413.html) ... his problem is the audio codec, TwoCC 0x0162 Windows Media Audio Professional V9, which wasn't supported as of Jan 2009 and may still be unsupported.

Comment: ffmpeg 0.5 (released in march 2009) supports wmv9 (http://ffmpeg.org/changelog.html) - @Sri Kumar: indicate your ffmpeg version and platform if you want someone to be able to help you.

Comment: SVN-r16573 is ffmpeg version and Xp (SP2) OS

Comment: @Sri Kumar - you should update your ffmpeg install, that one is a bit old